# Add elements using jQuery()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendto

Im trying to appendTo() element to document.
I have:

```
                    jQuery('<div/>', {
                        id: "1",
                        style: "float:right;",  
                        rel: data.uploadFileList[0].id,
                        onmouseover: ""                            
                    }.addClass("delete")                            
                        ).appendTo($("[id='"+value+"']").find('#'+parameter));  


                    jQuery('<a/>', {
                        href: url,
                        rel: "lightbox"
                    }).addClass("icon")
                    .appendTo($("[id='"+value+"']").find('#'+parameter));
```

Can I some how do it in one jQuery() ? Add two element one by one?

Comment: This code is fine. The only solution I see for adding in one jquery instruction would be with a html string. I'm not sure this would be an improvement if you prefer structured code.

Comment: I need add this tho elements <div> and <a> in one jQuery() but not in two

Comment: Why would it be better ?

Comment: OT question: Is the closing brace at ').appendTo' a mistake while you created your post?

Comment: You don't need this complex search : `$("[id='"+value+"']").find('#'+parameter)` is equivalent to `$('#'+parameter)` (expect if you're using the first part as a condition). An id is unique in a html document.

Comment: Yep. ').appendTo' its error. In real is '.appendTo'.

Answer (score 2):

Append as an array of jQuery elements. 
Use:

```
$([$('<div >', {
    id: "1",
    style: "float:right;",  
    rel: data.uploadFileList[0].id,
    onmouseover: ""                            
}), $('<a/>', {
    href: url,
    rel: "lightbox"
})]).appendTo($("[id='"+value+"']").find('#'+parameter))
```

Answer (score 1):

when you have all this HTML in your JS it tends to get muddy. I'd use a template and append the whole template to the element at once. Basic structure:

```
<script type="template/javascript" id="MyTemplate">                         
       <p>Hello {{name}}</p>                        
 </script>

<script>
var html = $("#MyTemplate").html()
                           .replace(/{{name}}/,name);
$("#someDiv").append(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want one simple statement, you could do

```
$('#'+parameter).append(
   '<div id=1 style="float:right;" rel="'+data.uploadFileList[0].id+'" class=delete></div>'
   + '<a href="'+url+'" rel="lightbox" class=icon></a>'
);
```

But is it really an improvement ?

Note that I supposed the first part of your complex element search isn't meant as a condition but is superfluous (an id can be present only once in a document).